# Custom process name not displaying in Launch4j

Tags: process, launch4j

So I open this xml in Launch4j but the process name is still javaw.exe

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>C:\Users\Nick\workspace\snake.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\Users\Nick\workspace\snake_game.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <customProcName>true</customProcName>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <restartOnCrash>false</restartOnCrash>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
    <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
    <maxVersion>1.8.0_31</maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <runtimeBits>64/32</runtimeBits>
  </jre>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Although customProcName is true it still doesn't name the process of my program snake_game.exe

Comment: You cannot change the process name of javaw.exe.  But, if you use the option <stayAlive>true</stayAlive> then the process snake_game.exe will also be listed in the processes while your java program is running, and killing it will kill the java process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Launch4j no longer supports setting custom process names. This feature was dropped because it could not be implemented without requiring administrator permissions on Windows after Windows introduced UAC in Windows 7.

Here's [the applicable bug filed in 2011 that was closed as "rejected" for this reason](http://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/95/).